# How to send events to client side via node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using client side to send a post request to node js server to perform a long request. During the process, I want the server side can let the client side know how much work is already done and which step it is currently in. So I am wondering if there is a way for the server side to constantly sending events where the client side can receive. Something that can be received by $(document).on(). But It doesn't have to be limited in this way though.

It seems to be $.post only takes data from server side once. So how can I be able to continuously receive server side data after posting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use socket.io to do that.

See this example https://github.com/socketio/socket.io

Answer (score 5):

Since you only want to send messages from the server to the client, you can also use
**Server-Sent Events (SSE)**.

You can setup listeners for the **SSEs** in your client-side script like this:

```
var serverEvents = new EventSource('http://localhost:8080/events');
serverEvents.addEventListener('message', function(event){
    console.log(event.data);
});
```

The browser will send a request to the URL provided when creating the new EventSource to establish a connection, then, from the server, you only need to send the messages in a particular format, for instance:

```
data: some data

data: {"name": "bobby"}
```

The individual messages must be separated by a pair of newline characters.

Node.js example:

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if( req.url === '/events'){
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      res.write('data: some data\n\n');
    }, 1000);
  }
});

server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

Check out this link for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Answer (score 2):

The only way for creating a real-time communication between server and client side is using [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). As already mentioned by @Nonemoticoner, the most famous websocket library is [Socket.io](http://socket.io/)